# Finding percentage as a subquery in Impala

Tags: subquery, impala

I am trying to find a percentage using the results of two individual subqueries. 
Both queries use the Counts of the same column, one using a where clause and one using the entire set.

First query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(col1))
FROM table
WHERE LOWER(col2) NOT IN ("value1", "value2")
```

Second query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(col1))
FROM table
```

I need the result of:

`(first query)/(second query) *100`

as a percentage, but I am not sure how to do this as Impala does not allow subqueries in select statement.

Comment: Why did you tag your question with `mysql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're on one of the latest versions (3.1.0 or higher), Impala does not support multiple `count(distinct)`s in one statement, see [IMPALA-110](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-110).

Perhaps you can split your query into multiple statements by using CTE. For example:

```
WITH q1 AS {
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(col1)) count1
  FROM table
  WHERE LOWER(col2) NOT IN ("value1", "value2")
),
q2 AS (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(col1)) count2
  FROM table
)
SELECT 100 * q1.count1 / q2.count2  result
FROM q1, q2
```

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  100.0 * COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LOWER(col2) NOT IN ("value1", "value2") THEN col1 END) / COUNT(DISTINCT col1)
FROM table
```

or:

```
SELECT 100.0 * COUNT(DISTINCT col1) / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col1) FROM table)
FROM table
WHERE LOWER(col2) NOT IN ("value1", "value2")
```

Comment: This seems to mostly work. However, the first "Distinct" throws an error (it works if I take this out and keep in the second distinct). Any thoughts on how to make the first part only count distinct?

Comment: As you can see here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tS283ypZ5FyPZiZAHV4ogs/0 there is no syntax error.

Comment: I think instead of using distinct in the first part, I instead need to group by "col1". Do you know if it's possible to use group by in this statement? Thanks!

Comment: Group by has nothing to do with the requirement as you described it in your question.

Comment: See another option with my 2nd query.

Comment: Unless you're on a latest version, Impala does not support multiple `count(distinct)`s in one statement. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-110